# How to handle usercase specific code in a public repo

Tags: git, production-environment, continuous-deployment

I few weeks ago I put my first ever project into production. No problems so far. This project of mine is also live on github and is intended to be used by others. Currently the server running my code pulls from this github repo to update.

I now want to implement some usecase specific code. An example is the including of the trace module from risingstack to monitor my application. Normaly i would put it in the code push it to github and it would land on my server. But this code is not usefull for most people. I don't want to cluter my repo with these thing.

This is the code at the begin of the code base in this specific situation:

```
require('@risingstack/trace');
```

How could i handle this situation?

Noah

edit: Added a small example

Comment: Add link to the github repository and sample of added code. It's hard to advice anything without examples

Comment: See the edit above